# Kafka get the partition id for a corresponding message ID

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am writing a Kafka consumer (in python) that needs to stream all the messages for a given key starting at a particular timestamp.

The cluster is using the default partitioning strategy and every message has been given a key, so I know that all the messages that I want are on a single partition.

The problem is, how can I find which partition my messages have been written to?

i.e. I need something like this... (pseudo code)

```py
import kafka
from kafka.structs import TopicPartition

target_msg_key = "3a11d08b-d635-490a-aa4e-16b282a599e6"

consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer([...])

# This doesn't exist?
partition_id = consumer.getPartitionIDforKey(target_msg_key)

tp = TopicPartition("my-topic",partition_id)

consumer.assign([tp])

for msg in consumer:
    ....
```

Basically, I need a way to convert a message key into the partition id (in python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find that logic in the source code of the [DefaultPartitioner](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/partitioner/default.py)

```
# given: all_partitions as a sorted list of numbers for the topic's partitions
idx = murmur2(key)
idx &= 0x7fffffff
idx %= len(all_partitions)
return all_partitions[idx]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful but it requires me to know how many partitions existed when the first message (for the key) was written.

Since the number of partitions isn't fixed, when I come to read the messages I can't use this approach.

Comment: Okay, I've realised that I'm completely wrong and that this is the right answer...

in short: no, you cannot (should not) change the number of partitions...

Comment: Well, you can change the number (but only increase is possible). From a consumer, there is a method `partitions_for_topic`, or something similar

Comment: Yeah, it's all fine except you will get the partition ID where new messages will be written, rather than the partition where the original messages are. But it's still good for what I need. Thanks!